# How to start/stop NodeJS server only once when running test suites

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, sails.js, mocha.js, webdriver-io

I'm writing selenium test suites for NodeJS. Here's one sample test file:

```
var Sails = require('sails');

// create a variable to hold the instantiated sails server
var app;
var client;

// Global before hook
before(function(done) {

  // Lift Sails and start the server
  Sails.lift({
    log: {
      level: 'error'
    },
    environment: 'test',
    port: 1338
  }, function(err, sails) {
    app = sails;
    done(err, sails);
  });
});

// Global after hook
after(function(done) {
  app.lower(done);
});

beforeEach(function(done) {
  client = require('webdriverjs').remote({desiredCapabilities:{browserName:'chrome'}});
  client.init(done);
});

afterEach(function(done) {
  client.end(done);
});

describe("Go to home page", function() {
  it('should work', function(done) {
    client
      .url('http://localhost:1338/')
      .pause(5000)
      .call(done);
  });
});
```

Currently:

- Starting each test file, it boots up the Sails server
- Finishing each test file, it shutdowns the Sails server
- Starting each test, it boots up the browser
- Finishing each test, it closes the browser

Therefore, if I have 10 selenium test files, it will boot/shutdown the Sails server 10 times. Is there any way to boot up the Sails server only once, running all test files, then shut it down?

I'm using Sails + Mocha + webdriverjs stack. Here's my Makefile config

```
test:
    @./node_modules/.bin/mocha -u bdd -R spec --recursive --timeout 15000
.PHONY: test
```

Answer (score 5):

One possible solution is to switch to using `npm test`, store your test execution line in your `package.json` file, and then take advantage of the `pretest` and `posttest` script phases.  Within these commands you could execute a script which will start up your server (`startSailsServer.js`), and shutdown your server, respectively.  You could then take out the starting and stopping of your server in each test file.

So your `package.json` would have something like this (you would have to move the start/stop sails server logic to these `startSailsServer.js` and `stopSailsServer.js` files):

```
"scripts": {
    "pretest": "node startSailsServer.js",
    "test": "./node_modules/.bin/mocha -u bdd -R spec --recursive --timeout 15000",
    "posttest": "node stopSailsServer.js"
}
```

Then to run your tests, you would execute `npm test`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for dylants suggestion, I edited the Makefile to utilize the "pre/post-test" script phases:

```
## Makefile
test:
    /bin/bash test/script/startServer.sh
    @./node_modules/.bin/mocha -u bdd -R spec --recursive --timeout 15000
    /bin/bash test/script/stopServer.sh

## test/script/startServer.sh
# Start Selenium
start-selenium &
echo $! > tmp/selenium.pid
sleep 1

# Start Node server
NODE_ENV=test PORT=1338 node app.js &
echo $! > tmp/test.pid

## test/script/stopServer.sh
kill -SIGINT $(cat tmp/selenium.pid)
kill -SIGINT $(cat tmp/test.pid)
```